# Phone authentication firebase fail because the phone number was blocked

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Yesterday, I did some tests for my application and after some attempts to verify my phone number, I got the following message:
"We have blocked all requests from this device due to unusual activity".
When I understood that for tests I have to supply a fictitious number, I did this, but now when I want to check my apk version I can't do that with my phone.
How can I unblock my number?
I tried to delete my phone number from users but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to whitelist your phone number for development purpose.

check this [Test with whitelisted phone numbers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#test-with-whitelisted-phone-numbers)

Comment: I did this, but now I want to do a test with actual SMS for my application and I can't, what can I do in this situation?

Comment: you need to use different phone number then

Comment: My phone number is blocked forever, or after a while, it will be possible again?

Comment: it will get unblock in while, but try to use whitelist number if possible

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended to use your actual phone number for testing multiple times, rather You should be using a test phone number added to your Firebase console.

Follow this,

Go to Sing-In Method in Authentication tab on Firebase Console.

Then,

Click on the “Phone numbers for testing” drop down and add a fake a phone number with fake code for testing.

Using phone numbers from this list will allow authentication without consuming your usage quota and sending actual SMS.

Comment: I did this, but now I want to do a real test with actual SMS for my application and I can't, what can I do in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

One this I found was my particular ISP didn't work with OTP Firebase so check with different ISPs might be helpful